# Trying to open Trace.axd gives 403 Forbidden

Tags: asp.net

Trying to open Trace.axd gives 403 Forbidden.
It's OK in dev mode from Visual Studio.
But not from the test web site.
I am signed in to the app with full security.
Have also got Elmah.axd and that's OK in test and dev.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to give ASP.NET worker process permission to read that file.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the property `localOnly` is set to false :

```
<trace enabled="true" localOnly="false" requestLimit="1000" />
```